# How to run tests from Docker in PhpStorm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpunit, phpstorm

I configured PhpStorm for running tests from docker container in the IDE by clicking the Run button, but I got the following error when I run them:

> Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException : An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

from .env:

```env
database_host: sp_mysql
database_port: null
```

docker-compose:

```yaml
version: "3.4"

services:

  nginx:
    container_name: sp_nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./var/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx:cached
      - ./web:/app/web
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - internal

  php:
    container_name: sp_php
    image: sp/php
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/php/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - internal

  mysql:
    container_name: sp_mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

But if I go directly to php container it works:

```
docker exec -it sp_php vendor/bin/phpunit
```

i setup my ide Docker/PHPUnit config by this guide:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I7aGWO6K3Ho&t=240s

Comment: Can you share your PHPStorm config (for the testing suite) as you have something not correctly configured there

Comment: Sorry, what's `sp_php` in your `docker exec -it sp_php`, while you have only `php` service in your compose file.? And why you're not checking with `docker compose`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti sure, sry can't attach image to post yet https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEfpg.png
If you interested i also added how i configured this to post

Comment: @Dmitrii it's container name, you can go into container by it

Comment: You must use the container name (not `container_name` but the parent). So instead of `sp_mysql` use `mysql` on your `.env` and see if that works (`container_name` only works internally, not for hosts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem i set this in .env

```
host: "172.19.0.1" // docker network bridge gateway
port: "3308"       // my db port from docker-compose
```

https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/